# Laravel behaving madly - showing wrong images

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website satoshirps.site

When a new user registers, his profile photo remains empty.
Then goto [Upload picture](http://www.satoshirps/upload) to upload a profile picture.

After returning back to dashboard (www.satoshirps.site/dashboard) the user see his uploaded profile picture. Now goto [delete picture](http://www.satoshirps/delete) to delete the current profile picture and then upload an another profile picture using upload.

This time returning to dashboard gives the old picture(which is weird).

When I tried this thing, I uploaded the picture successfully for the second time (I checked the file in my app's folder). Then I was not getting the correct image. Does lavarel have cache or this is a cookie problem. I tried again by deleting browser's cache and cookie but nothing worked.

The upload page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  @if(Session::has('success'))
      {{ Session::get('success') }}
@endif

@if(Session::has('error'))
        {{ Session::get('error') }}
@endif

  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'upload', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post')) }}
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  {{ Form::file('image') }}
  {{ Form::submit('Upload') }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
</body>
</html>
```

The controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Input;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Image;
use Storage;
use App\User;
use File;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  /**
  * Show the application dashboard.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
  public function index()
  {
    return view('home');
  }

  public function dashboard()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('dashboard', compact('user'));
  }

  public function upload()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('upload', compact('user'));
  }

  public function uploadsave(Request $request)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
      $filename = 'profilepics/'.$user->username.'.jpg';
      File::delete($filename);
      $img = Image::make($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])->encode('jpg',75)->resize(200,200)->save('profilepics/'.$user->username.'.jpg');
      $dbuser = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
      $dbuser->photo_path = '/profilepics/'.$user->username.'.jpg';
      $dbuser->save();  //update user's profile picture location
      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfull');
      return Redirect::to('upload');
    }
    else {
      // sending back with error message.
      Session::flash('error', 'Uploaded file is not valid');
      return Redirect::to('upload');
    }
  }


  public function deletephoto()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $filename = 'profilepics/'.$user->username.'.jpg';
    File::delete($filename);
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
      echo "The image is not deleted";
    } else {
      echo "The image is deleted";
    }
  }
}
```

And the routes file

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  Route::auth();
  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard');
  Route::get('/upload', 'HomeController@upload');
  Route::post('/upload', 'HomeController@uploadsave');
  Route::get('delete', 'HomeController@deletephoto');
});
```

Also if you visit dashboard after deleting the file you will see your old profile picture

Please some will please try this and help me.

Comment: does it work if you CTRL+F5 after your new upload?

Comment: You can check it yourself. I have provided link to website but your approach also doesn't work.

Comment: It says that your site cannot be reached (EDIT: your urls don't include .site)

Comment: The website can be down sometime because I is a self hosted and it is running on laptop which over heats sometimes. But now check it

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#deleting-files), to delete files you should use `Storage::delete($filename)`

Save your pictures in the storage directory and serve them by creating a route as follows in your `UsersController`:

```
public function profilePicture($user){
    $profile_picture_url = storage_path().'/profile_pictures/'.$user['id'].'/profile.jpg';

    if(!File::exists( $profile_picture_url ))
        App::abort(404);

    return Image::make($profile_picture_url)->response('jpg');
}
```

Then, in your Views, create img tags using the `HTML` and the `URL` helper from Laravel:

```
HTML::image(URL::action('UsersController@profilePicture', array($user['id'])))
```

Make sure you have the [Intervention package](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) installed and you are good to go

Comment: Storage::delete($filename) will delete files from App\storage\app\public\profilepics (which do not exits). But the pictures are stored in App\public\profilepics

Comment: Read the full documentation, in the configuration section it is clearly mentioned [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#configuration)

Comment: Why don't you save images in the storage folder?

Comment: I tried that too but another problem arised that how to retrieve them because "Storage" will give the contents of jpg stored not the file name.

Comment: Also i tried by changing storage path in config/filesystem.php but none works.

Comment: I handle it using a route. At the moment I'm working on serving images, but you can check my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel/36066273#36066273

Comment: I liked your approach and I am getting perfect results but how should I pass that url or image to a view (dashboard)

Comment: use the built-in url builder URL::action('Controller@action', array($params))

Comment: Can you elaborate, how to use this?

Comment: getting a big error `Action App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@profilePicture not defined. (View: /home/yash/website/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)` I solved it by including profilePicture in routes file

Comment: But when I goto dashboard I see blank image and when I saw its source I found this `<img src="http://satoshirps.site/profilepics?8">` which should be `<img src="http://satoshirps.site/profilepics/8/profile.jpg">`

Comment: I think it depends from your Laravel version. Please refer to this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-action

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2.22, what version did you use while coding this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106747/discussion-between-clod986-and-yash-lotan).