# Uploading images and show in front-end with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4. I want to upload images with my blog. 
So I have uploaded images in `storage/app/public/upload` folder like this.

```
$request->file('file')->storeAs('upload', $fileName);
```

It is uploading images correctly. But my problem in displaying images in front end with blog.

I want to show image like below

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/app/public/upload/'.$imagename)}}" />
```

It's add image path `http://127.0.0.1:3000/storage/app/public/upload/man.png`

But still image is not visible.

Comment: Related - [How should I serve an image with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$path = storage_path();
<img src="{{asset($path .'app/public/upload/'.$imagename)}}" />
```

For more Info please read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image directly, from URL, you need to specify the disk as **public**:
`$request->file('file')->storeAs('upload', $fileName, 'public');`
After you set the disk, you must create symlink from storage/app/public to public/storage folder via this command:
`php artisan storage:link`
And your asset url could look like this:
`<img src="{{ asset('storage/upload/' . $fileName) }}" />`