# Laravel fail to return image

Tags: php, laravel, file-handling

I've a image and some text file in storage folder other than the public folder. the folder architecture is 
storage
|->uploads

and set a route like

```
Route::get('storage/{folder}/{filename}','FileController@getFile');
```

inside the Controller the getFile method have following code

```
  $path = storage_path($folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
if (extension_loaded('fileinfo')) {
        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $file = File::get($path);
        $type = File::mimeType($path);
        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
        return $response;
    }
    else{
        abort(412,'please enable the fileinfo extension or contact site administration');
    }
```

when i try to retrieve the image from url it return the blank image like this
[blank image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDA3.png)

but when i try to retrive the text file it return the file

Also tried it with `Image::make($path)` and `response()->file($path)` when the mime type is image/* still the output is same..
so How do i show my image file from url without using the public folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I serve an image with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel)

Comment: already tried the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel) but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it... I also check for user permissions but i adapted it to your needs...

```
public function getFile()
{
    $path = storage_path($folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

    return response()->file($path);
}
```

Comment: used that as well but didn't get the file. The file path is correct and file exist as well .

Comment: What happens when you print the path? by the way, i usually store the path within the DB not just the filename... This is not how i calculate the route... i just adapted my code to yours. :/

Comment: @erubile it return the full file path ` "E:\ecommerce\storage\uploads\7ef33eac189a8006c22af9ce66a2b096.jpg"` and when entering this path in explorer address bar the file opened and also tried in browser url bar with file protocol file:///E:/ecommerce/storage/uploads/7ef33eac189a8006c22af9ce66a2b096.jpg and it worked as well

Comment: what kind of permissions do the folder and the enclosed content have ? does everyone have permission to read?

Comment: Also, i don't think we use the same dev enviroment, i use vagrant homestead... my paths does not look like that

Comment: This is how my paths look: //home/vagrant/Code/myproject/storage/uploads/contactos/6917/image/1534686660SomeSome.png

Comment: yes all user have full permission on the folder and that is the default path formate of windows

Comment: Also i've other text file like pdf and text as well and the same code return the text files

Comment: mmmm what happens if you append the file protocol to either your code or the one i passed you?

Comment: if this worked file:///E:/ecommerce/storage/uploads/7ef33eac189a8006c22af9ce66a2b096.jpg

Comment: this also should work: return response()->file('file:///E:/ecommerce/storage/uploads/7ef33eac189a8006c22af9ce66a2b096.jpg');