# Apache & Laravel - What's the best way to protect video without losing performance?

Tags: html, laravel, video-streaming

I'm currently uploading profile videos to the public folder.

The cool thing here is that you can simply use the public URL in your HTML5 video tag to stream it.

I could do another route call that only logged in users could access, but this apparently affects performance a lot based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel/36477345#36477345).

Is there a way that if you put the URL in the browser navbar (meaning, not embbeded in a HTML5 video tag) I don't allow you to acccess the file?

Can I also block calls coming from different domains? (Embbeded in a HTML5 video tag in another site)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the uploaded files in a non-public folder, then have a controller which controls whether or not someone is allowed to access it (e.g. only authenticated users). If a request is valid, you can return a [streamed response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads).

The performance impact in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066144/how-should-i-serve-an-image-with-laravel/36477345#36477345) is not caused by having a controller wrap the request, it's caused by the controller regenerating images instead of simply returning them in a response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PtrTon ,  but if I'm working with vue.js, identifying users via a bearer token, how can I stream the response? What should I set in the HTML5 video tag so it works?

Comment: I think a streamed response (with the right headers) will be playable in a `<video>` tag. When rendering the HTML5 video tag, use the route for the controller as the `src` property. Something like `<video :src="video.url" controls></video>`.

Comment: Correct, but how do I send the bearer token there? I would need to first make an axios call to the route, get back the response, and inject it somehow to the video src?

Comment: Ah I understand the issue you're facing now. I don't have a solid solution for you since you'll need all your requests to go through axios and a src property of a `<video>` handles requests itself. You could go for a few alternatives: generate a one-time-valid url, invalidate the video url after an hour, try controlling the request the `<video>` element does or try a player which you can control